# How do I limit my moment js duration values to only 2 digits?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to work with date times which are calculated from distance/speed.  I am also using the [moment duration format plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).  When I pass the value to `moment.duration` and then format it some of the values are more than 2 digits, i.e.

```
39:3452:98762
```

I would like this to format correctly as `HH:mm:ss`.  Here is my code.

```
var point1Time = 19.188019795;
var d1 = moment.duration(point1Time, 'hours');

var d1Hours = d1.format('HH');
var d1Mins = d1.format('mm', {forceLength: true });
var d1Secs = d1.format('ss', {forceLength: true });
```

As you can see the `point1Time` (which I've entered as a number for the sake of this example) is miles/speed, I then pass this value to `moment` as a `duration` in `hours`.  After that I try to separate the `HH:mm:ss` using `format`.  The value that is returned is something like `d1Hours: 19`, `d1Mins: 1151`, `d1Secs: 69076`.

I thought that adding `forceLength` would help keep the digits down to two only but it didn't work as I can't see where to define that limit.

Can anyone assist with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'HH:mm:ss'` as template in [`format()`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) method to get the desired output.

`d1.format('mm')` and `d1.format('ss')` give the output of [`asSeconds`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/) and [`asMinutes`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) while I think that you need the output of [`minutes()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) and [`seconds()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/).

Here a live sample:

```js
var point1Time = 19.188019795;
var d1 = moment.duration(point1Time, 'hours');

console.log(d1.format('HH:mm:ss'));

console.log(d1.minutes(), d1.asMinutes());
console.log(d1.seconds(), d1.asSeconds());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the duration into seconds then it's easy to find the format that you want

```
var d1 = moment.duration(point1Time, 'hours');
var asSecs = d1.asSeconds()

var HHMMSS = secondsToHHMMSS(asSecs)


function pad(num) {
    return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}

function secondsToHHMMSS(secs) {
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    secs = secs%3600;
    var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    secs = secs%60;
    return pad(hours)+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(secs);
}
```